# Error on url rewrite .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Actually, I'm not fluent in the use. Htaccess file, the following lines of code are fetched me from using the internet. But now it gets some unexpected error. 
The first bug: when I entered `http://localhost/giccos/wall/username` (pretty good showing and error but when I add it to the rear .php moment it into `http://localhost/giccos/wall/username?username=username` and if I can fix it to remain `http://localhost/giccos/wall/username?username=usernames2312312s` page this time) 
How do I fix this? I want it kind of like facebook, if we add .php normal operation.

And here is my mess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /giccos/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^status/(.*).php status.php?status_id=$1
RewriteRule ^hashtag/(.*).php hashtag.php?hashtag=$1
RewriteRule ^wall/(.*).php wall.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*).php blog.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^verify/user/(.*).php verify.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^groups/(.*).php groups.php?groups_id=$1
#RewriteRule ^life/(.*) $1.php
RewriteRule ^life/ newsfeed.php
DirectoryIndex home.php
Options All -Indexes
## Auto remove .PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you even understand what these rules are doing? How can you download and start using something without even explaining your requirements?

Comment: I really did not understand them :( I just downloaded and put it on trial, (on localhost)

Comment: Can you give us more details about what you want (and not just what you have tried) ?

Comment: I want to write off some links in the paragraph like this: **`RewriteRule ^status/(.*).php status.php?status_id=$1
RewriteRule ^hashtag/(.*).php hashtag.php?hashtag=$1
RewriteRule ^wall/(.*).php wall.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*).php blog.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^verify/user/(.*).php verify.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^groups/(.*).php groups.php?groups_id=$1`** And to add some code so that it can automatically remove .php and when users on my site (mysite.com), it will automatically switch to (mysite.com/newsfeed)